# Строго придерживаться чего-то нестрогого

Tags: семантика

У Пушкина: **"Мой дядя самых честных правил"**.
Это скрытая цитата, если кто не знает (из Дмитриева, кажется), но речь не об этом.

Что означает такая характеристика? Что человек честно (то есть "строго") придерживался неких правил (совсем не обязательно благой и высокой морали) или что его правила были честными (то есть он был порядочным человеком)?

Казалось бы, вопрос не совсем уместный, по контексту можно понять что Онегин характеризует дядю именно честным человеком, иронически, правда.

Но вот диалог (почти реальный, только сокращенный).

- Он строго придерживается поста.
- Но пост-то не строгий?
- А он строго придерживается его правил.

Тут собеседники по-разному понимают смысл "строго (честно)  придерживаться чего-то".

А чем правила онегинского дяди лучше? Почему у Пушкина невозможно двоякое прочтение? Неужели дело только в контексте?

Comment: Это Крылова басня, не Дмитриева. Причем сюжет - лафонтеновский вроде бы. А вопросец-то с подвохом. )))

Answer (score 2):

Вы предлагаете не придерживаться контекста, но ведь именно из контекста мы можем понять настоящее отношение героя к своему родственнику.

Во-первых, речь идёт не о каких-то ("неких")правилах, а именно о принципах нравственности. В  «Словаре языка Пушкина» приводятся многочисленные примеры употребления  поэтом  и фразеологизма"человек честных правил"(галлицизм "человек набожных правил")  и обычного словосочетания «честный человек».

Во-вторых, ирония, конечно, в характеристике есть,она у Пушкина везде есть, и не только по отношению к  дядюшке, а и к Е.Онегину, и к себе, и к читателю. Герой его иронизирует  над  дядей,(чья добропорядочность только в том, что он ничего плохого не делал, бранился от скуки с ключницей,пил настойку, в окно смотрел и мух давил) «начитанным» читателем и над собой, но не подвергает сомнению "честные правила" дяди.

Он иронизирует над собой, что ему нужно следовать правилам в обществе и выказывать уважение больному родственнику, а не над дядей, которого не за что уважать, кроме как за наследство.

Речь о значении союза «когда» в строке «Когда не в шутку занемог…»,оно  использовано Пушкиным в значении «если».
(Например: «Когда(если) б я знал, что это всё произойдёт так, а не иначе, я бы …»).
Эти строчки следует понимать так: «Если дядя действительно серьёзно заболел, то, пожалуй, нужно показывать, что уважаешь его». Такое понимание находится в согласии со следующими строками:
«Вздыхать и думать про себя:
Когда же черт возьмет тебя…»

Иначе получается, что Онегин "не самых честных правил", если мы понимаем: «Когда дядя серьёзно заболел, он заставил своего племянника ухаживать за собой и уважать себя только потому, что обещал ему большое наследство в виде деревенского имения. И никакого любовно-патриархального чувства к своему дяде Евгений Онегин не испытывал, так как они не были духовно близки». Он вообще никаких чувств к нему не испытывал, судя по жизни в городе,но нужно поддерживать "светский этикет".

Comment: За экскурс - спасибо. Только я совсем не предлагаю читать Пушкина без контекста. Я о грамматике и семантике конструкции "быть каких-то правил". Пушкин, если угодно, тут только пример фразы с таким построением.

Comment: А если о грамматике фразы, то здесь речь именно о порядочности дяди, о правилах поведения в порядочном обществе, "честные правила" -фразеологизм - калька с французского со значением "правила чести", т.е. чтимые, уважаемые в порядочном обществе  принципы нравственности, поведения. Это книжное выражение из официально-деловой речи (офиц. характеристики). В том и ирония, что считать " честным" поведением, что уважалось в светском обществе.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, у Пушкина все однозначно: дядя соблюдает "честные правила", дядя соблюдает их строго (ведь сказано, что он - человек этих правил). Осталось понять, что такое "честные правила" и "не в шутку". Думаю, честные правила - это правила требующие честности и справедливости. "Не в шутку занемог" может иметь два смысла: (1) заболел, а не притворился больным (честность),  (2) заболел тяжело, то есть как только понял, что пришла пора уйти и оставить наследство, он не заставил себя долго ждать (справедливость - с точки зрения Онегина, конечно).

Comment: Кащей не в шутку захворал, 
Пять дней уж с сундука не сходит; 
Не ест, не пьет и глаз почти не сводит; 
Пришло невмочь, за лекарем послал. 
[А. Е. Измайлов. Кащей и лекарь (1817.12.29)]

Comment: Мне кажется, что в пушкинские времена, выражение "не в шутку" понимали не иначе как: "на самом деле", "без дураков", "очень серьезно".

Comment: @guaranteen - вот с этим я согласен. Но только с этим.

Comment: М_Г, а вот скажите, честные правили и их строгое соблюдение  - одно из другого вытекает? Если да, то что из этого первично, если нет, то что основное, а что пристегнуто контекстом?

Comment: @Иванов7-й, Не вижу причин считать, что одно из другого вытекает. Правила сами по себе. А вот то, что дядя - человек этих правил ("мой дядя (-)  (человек) самых честних правил"), говорит об их строгом соблюдении.

Comment: Не допускаю мысли, что автора ЕО можно заподозрить в том, что для него смысл словосочетаний: «честных правил» (т.е., справедливых, благородных) и «строгих правил» (т.е., жестких, суровых, беспощадных) был почти эквивалентен.

Comment: Что касается расширенного: «самых честных правил», - то прошу (вслед за мной) согласиться с мнением исследователей, кои считают его летучим выражением, «выпорхнувшим» из популярной в те годы басни.

Comment: Прямое сопоставление осел = дядя предлагаю считать примитивом. При прочтении фразы «…дядя самых честных правил…» (лично у меня) наряду с симпатией к «дяде», как искреннему, усердному, рьяному служаке (вере, царю и отечеству), возникает и  чувство снисходительности к его (дяди) неспособности понимать, принимать и учитывать (но не вытаптывать!!!) иные (новые) ценности.

Comment: Простите великодушно, должен был написать: "АВТОРА ЕО"

Answer (score 0):

«Евге́ний Оне́гин» (дореф. «Евгеній Онѣгинъ») — роман в стихах русского поэта Александра Сергеевича Пушкина, написанный в 1823—1831 годах, одно из самых значительных произведений русской словесности.

Двоюродный дядя по матери Луки Андреича, человек старого века, честных правил и при грубой наружности внутренно чувствительный, узнал на другой день приключение племянника на улице и княжны в доме. [Ф. В. Ростопчин. Ох, французы! (1812)]

Осел был самых честных правил: 
Ни с хищностью, ни с кражей незнаком, 
Не поживился он хозяйским ни листком
И птицам, грех сказать, чтобы давал потачку; 
Но Мужику барыш был с огорода плох. 
[И. А. Крылов. Осел и мужик (1818)] [

Чем пошлости омут бездонный, 
Что много так жертв поглотил, 
Где много так гибнет бесследно
И честных стремлений и сил. 
[А. Н. Плещеев. «Смотрю на нее и любуюсь...» (1864)]

Найду ли мужа-друга? Одинока, 40 лет, честных правил. Воронеж, предъяв. почт. кв. [Объявления (1911.09.03) // «Брачная Газета», 1911]

Чтить - Происходит от праслав. *čьstiti, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: укр. чтити, ччу, словенск. častíti — то же, др.-чеш.. čstíti, чешск. ctít, словацк. сtit᾽, польск. czcić, н.-луж. pócćiś ро-сеsćiś «почтить». Форма чтить получена из *чьстити от чьсть (см. честь), причем ч- — результат вторичного влияния слова честь Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера

Синонимы к «чЕстный / честнОй»: благородный, безупречный, бесхитростный, достойный, искренний, непогрешимый, открытый, порядочный, почитаемый, приличный, справедливый, уважаемый, чтимый…

Здесь только цитаты. В качестве комментария можно добавить, что "строгий" и "честный" синонимами не являются.

Answer (score 0):

А вопросец-то с подвохом. )))

Я так понимаю, вы хотите формального ответа на вопрос, почему Пушкина нельзя прочитать иначе, чем принято? А в контексте "соблюдать строгий пост" - можно? Я так думаю, что контекст любой из этих фраз сам по себе достаточен для однозначного  понимания. Но ведь есть же еще и Пушкин с его невообразимым богатством выразительных средств.

Начнем с якобы первоисточника.

.---

ОСЕЛ И МУЖИК

Мужик на лето в огород
Наняв Осла, приставил
Ворон и воробьев гонять нахальный род.
Осел был самых честных правил:
Ни с хищностью, ни с кражей незнаком:
Не поживился он хозяйским ни листком,
И птицам, грех сказать, чтобы давал потачку;
Но Мужику барыш был с огорода плох.
Осел, гоняя птиц, со всех ослиных ног,
Такую поднял скачку,
Что в огороде всё примял и притоптал.
Увидя тут, что труд его пропал,
Крестьянин на спине ослиной
Убыток выместил дубиной.
«И ништо!» все кричат: «скотине поделом!
С его ль умом
За это дело браться?»

А я скажу, не с тем, чтоб за Осла вступаться;
Он, точно, виноват (с ним сделан и расчет),
Но, кажется, не прав и тот,
Кто поручил Ослу стеречь свой огород.

.---
(И. А. Крылов)

И вот тут-то действительно обыгрывается понятие "честности" Осла. Да, он по-своему честен, честно - что, как верно замечено, здесь почти синонимично  "строго" - следует своему пониманию своих честных, но глупых правил. А что с него взять, он же Осел?! (Хотя мораль басни, конечно, не в этом).

Ирония Онегина тоже очевидна. Дядя в его понимании - честный дурак. То есь аналогия есть. Вопрос связи одного с другим я вывожу за скобки (см. комментарий Людмилы).

Теперь по сути. Полагаю, у вас просто логическая ошибка.
Оборот **"строго соблюдает пост"** при очень большом желании еще может быть интерпретирован как **"соблюдает строгий пост"**, но не наоборот.
Сравните: "строго воспитывать детей" - это и держать их в строгость и строго ("честно", как вы предлагаете) придерживаться каких-то норм, правил, диктующих воспитание. Но если сказано, что "правила строгие", то разночтения исключены.

Так вот, у Крылова, а потом и у Онегина, использован именно второй, недвусмысленный вариант. Правила у дяди (и у Осла) были честные. **Двусмысленность, ироничность возникают только в крыловском контексте. И оторванная от Крылова фраза Онегина никаким образом не могла бы быть двусмысленной.**

Comment: Ю.М.Лотман категорически не согласился  с этой версией: «Встречающееся в комментариях к ЕО утверждение, что выражение «самых честных правил...» — цитата из басни Крылова «Осел и мужик» («Осел был самых честных правил...»), не представляется убедительным. Крылов использует не какое-либо редкое речение, а живой фразеологизм устной речи той поры (ср.: «...он набожных был правил..»  в басне «Кот и повар»). Крылов мог быть для  Пушкина в данном случае лишь образцом обращения к устной, живой речи. Современники вряд ли воспринимали это как литературную цитату».

Comment: Людмила, это хорошо, что Лотман, но я и не говорю, что у Пушкина - прямая цитата. Это автор вопроса.  Я не рассматриваю вопрос как литературоведческий вовсе.  "И оторванная от Крылова фраза Онегина никаким образом не могла бы быть двусмысленной" - что тут оспорить можно на основании мнения Лотмана? У Крылова она двусмысленно-ироничная, у Пушкина - только если связать её с Крыловым (что, согласен, далеко не всеми признается).   В отношении "набожных" правил тут даже и говорить не о чем. Набожность в принципе не может быть истолкована как нечто "строгое". Лотману лотманово, а кесарю кесарево.

Comment: @Людмила, я по вашему комментарию уточнил в тексте этот момент,  но всё остальное никак не пострадало.

Comment: Да, это Крылов, конечно. А в чем еще "подвох"? Вы вопрос поняли правильно, и я ответ ваш понял. Вот еще не знаю, согласен ли с ним. Я же не о двусмысленности "второго варианта".

Comment: Подвох именно в том, что казалось бы очевидная вещь, а не все так просто. Я вот не знаю, как Лотман объясняет совпадение слов "самых [честных]". Если правила "честные" - в том понимании, о котором говорит Людмила и некоторые авторы - то это относительное прилагательное, и у него не должно быть сравнительных степеней. Это как "более деревянное".  Или вот само непонимание "современного человека" о котором вы Sibylla заспорили (и правильно, что заспорили). Но это все какие-то побочные моменты. Вывод и резюме моего ответа - в последней фразе и двух абзацах над ней. Остальное - второстепенно.

Comment: "это относительное прилагательное, и у него не должно быть сравнительных степеней. Это как "более деревянное"." - @Мимоходов почему?

Comment: @Иванов7-й Что почему? Почему относительное? Более честный - возможно только в прямом значении "честный", качественном. А относительное дает "более построенный на чести" - это как "немножко беременный". Понятно, что в шутку сказать можно, но чтоб эта шутка (весьма современная, кстати) независимо пришла в голову Пушкину и Крылову... Лотман чего-то прошляпил тут. Но, повторяю, это вещи побочные.

Comment: @Мимоходов Я понял мысль. Спасибо. Не уверен, что я с ней соглашусь..

Answer (score 0):

Вместо вступления.

Интересно, когда-нибудь какому-нибудь педагогу пришла в голову мысль предложить детям написать сочинение на тему "Как я понимаю первые четыре строки из "Евгения Онегина".
 Когда современный человек начинает читать "Евгения Онегина", он не понимает ничего, хотя вроде бы все слова понятны. Тогда он обычно пропускает и забывает  их, но однажды всё-таки может вернуться и поразмышлять над сутью сказанного. Он опять не понимает ничего и обращается к разным источникам за помощью. Но оказывается и ученые-филологи, и филологи-любители не очень-то в этом разобрались.

Что за честные правила?

Говорят, что "Пушкин взял это выражение из басни Крылова И.А. "Осел и Мужик" (1818 - 1819). В этой басне Осел "самых честных правил" старался выполнить свой долг как можно лучше, но как он ни старался, ничего не выходило. С выражением связана следующая история. Крылов вместе с Пушкиным, Вяземским и другими играли в фанты и Крылову досталось "Залезть под стол и написать басню". Крылов, как известно, был крупным человеком. Столик же, под который ему следовало залезть — маленький. Как только Крылов залез под стол, он тут же придумал басню из одной строчки — "Осел был самых честных правил".

Но вот Лотман отрицает связь первых строк с басней**, поэтому смысл "честных правил" так и остается неясным. Заболевший человек требует к себе уважения — в этом правила? Но говорят, что  в то время фраза «**он уважать себя заставил»** означало смерть человека, тогда становятся понятными чувства наследника: "и лучше выдумать не мог". Честное правило жизни — это прожить отпущенные тебе годы и вовремя уйти, уступив место другим?

Если же обратиться к басни Крылова, то можно сделать вывод, что честные правила не помогли Ослу правильно и честно  исполнить свои обязательства. Всё условно и относительно, честность и строгость, и чем строже пост, тем более склонен к грешной жизни человек, которому нужны эти  строгие запреты.
- [Правильно ли читатель XXI века понимает смысл первых строк романа А.С. Пушкина «Евгений Онегин»? | shkolazhizni.ru](https://shkolazhizni.ru/culture/articles/57106/)
- [Мой дядя самых честных правил | dslov.ru](http://dslov.ru/pos/p370.htm)

Comment: огда современный человек читает первые строки "Евгения Онегина", он не понимает ничего,- это слишком категоричное утверждение. Все все понимают. Другое дело, каким образом, на основании чего приходит это понимание. И вот это в чем-то связано с моим вопросом.

Comment: Понимают, что здесь ирония, но неясно, в чем она конкретно заключается. Особенно последняя строчка: "и лучше выдумать не мог".  Я ее без комментариев не понимаю, мне раньше казалось, что Пушкин ее для рифмы добавил, без особого смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается диалога, то второй собеседник спонтанно (не успев осознать всей сути сказанного) отреагировал на *ключевое слово* "строгий", отнеся его к "**строгому посту**", на что первый собеседник затем обратил его внимание, мол, вы же понимаете, что я имел в виду **строгое соблюдение предписанного**, будь оно "строгим" или "не строгим" в своих внутренних аспектах. В результате должно было прийти взаимопонимание, в диалоге *не было некорректных* высказываний - **можно** строго соблюдать нечто в себе не строгое.

**P.S.** Я не вижу проблем с пониманием пушкинских слов: можно искать в них скрытые смыслы (в пушкиноведческих целях), а можно не искать и понимать всё буквально и однозначно. Вероятно, Пушкин намеренно использовал ещё не избитое, но уже узнаваемое 
словосочетание "самых честных правил", смысл которого (как и выражения "лучше выдумать не мог") выглядит вполне прозрачным (мой дядя - человек вполне порядочный: этакое предложение "сделки" с его стороны было предельно разумным, и всё по-честному; буду вести себя хорошо - стану наследником). Точно так же в нашу эпоху возникают фразеологизмы, впервые изречённые известными людьми. Если встроить их в какой-нибудь текст, они будут узнаваемы и будут указывать на источник, который современникам известен:

Мой дядя - он хотел как лучше,

А получилось как всегда.

Хворнул всерьёз и пишет тут же:

Кати, племянничек, сюда!